# How to find the steady state probability of a markov chain using gaussian elimination?

Tags: systems-of-equations, markov-chains, gaussian-elimination

Need help understanding how to properly setup the gaussian table. How/when do I use the last row ($\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3+\pi_4 =1$) of the systems? Does it appear as $\left[1\;1\;1\;1\;|\;1 \right] $from the beginning? Just need help with the first few steps to get me started.

Example 
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcl}
 .7π_1 &+&   0    &+&   0    &+& .03π_4 &=& π_1 \\
.06π_1 &+&  .7π_2 &+& .15π_3 &+& .03π_4 &=& π_2 \\
.18π_1 &+& .18π_2 &+&  .7π_3 &+& .24π_4 &=& π_3 \\
.06π_1 &+& .12π_2 &+& .15π_3 &+&  .7π_4 &=& π_4 \\
   π_1 &+&    π_2 &+&    π_3 &+&    π_4 &=& 1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Got the values from a transition matrix. Answer: $0.0311,0.2442,0.4139,0.3108$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace any of the four equations (e.g. last one) with the last equation $\pi_1+\cdots+ \pi_4=1$ to form the augmenterd matrix (note all $\pi$s were transfered to the left):
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  -0.3&0&0&0.03&0\\
  0.06&-0.3&0.15&0.03&0\\
  0.18&0.18&-0.3&0.24&0\\
  1&1&1&1&1\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
Can you solve it using the Gauss elimination method?